How to programmatically set alerts for failure in a W&B run?
How to programmatically set alerts for failure in a W&B run?
I'm trying to set up alerts in my W&B (Weights & Biases) project to notify me if a run fails. I've been testing several functions I thought would work based on my research, but none seem to be implemented in the W&B API. Here's the code snippet where I attempt to set up these notifications:
import wandb

mode = 'dryrun'
run_name = 'my_run'
num_batches = 50
path = '/data'
name = 'experiment1'
today = '2023-08-01'
probabilities = [0.1, 0.9]
batch_size = 32
data_mixture_name = 'mix1'

debug = mode == 'dryrun'
run = wandb.init(mode=mode, project="beyond-scale", name=run_name, save_code=True)
wandb.config.update({
    "num_batches": num_batches, 
    "path": path, 
    "name": name, 
    "today": today, 
    'probabilities': probabilities, 
    'batch_size': batch_size, 
    'debug': debug, 
    'data_mixture_name': data_mixture_name
})

# Attempts to set notifications
run.notify_on_failure()
run.notify_on_crash()
run.notify_on_exit()
run.notify_on_heartbeat()
run.notify_on_abort()

Each of these attempts results in an AttributeError, stating that the 'Run' object has no such attribute. For example:
AttributeError: 'Run' object has no attribute 'notify_on_failure'

Is there a correct method to set up failure or other alerts in W&B? If so, how should I modify my approach?
ref: https://community.wandb.ai/t/how-do-i-set-the-wandb-alert-programatically-for-my-current-run/4891

You could use wandb.alert(...) inside a try/except block.
Check the docs here: https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/runs/alert
